# How to exclude list of file names or file types when getting list of objects from boto3?

Tags: python-3.x, boto3

I want to exclude 3 files by name and/or open to excluding them by file type (All 3 files end in `.csv`) when I make a call with boto3 to get a list of objects in a s3 bucket.

Currently I am listing all objects like so:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

objs = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='mybucket_name')['Contents']
```

But not sure how to filter out the files or `.csv` at this point. How can I filter out file names or file extension from the `objs` variable ideally? I have this piece of code ready to get the file name of the lastest modified file:

```
last_added = [obj['Key'] for obj in sorted(objs, key=get_last_modified)][-1]
```

However I can get a list of file names that **dont have** '.csv' (in this case the files not have any extensions) file type ,like so:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket_name')
files = my_bucket.objects.all()
file_list = []
for file in files:
    if file.key.endswith(''):
         file_list.append(file.key)
```

This doesnt tell me the last modified date however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the AWS API itself does not offer the option to filter by suffix and/or exclusion pattern, you would simply have to filter the returning list by yourself:

```
last_added = max(
    (
        obj for obj in s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='mybucket_name')['Contents']
        if not obj['Key'].endswith('.csv')
    ),
    key=lambda obj: obj['LastModified']
)
```