# python boto3 list objects excluding a particular folder

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have the next S3 folder structure:

```
/my_folder
          ->(some files inside my_folder)
          ->/logs/
          ->/processed/
          ->/another_folder/
```

I want to list all the files inside **/my_folder**, but excluding these files inside **/logs** folder. How can I do that?

I've tested [list_objects_v2](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) but `files` it is still getting all the files inside **/logs** folder:

```
files = s3.list_objects_v2(
    Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Prefix=input_key, Delimiter="/logs"
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to exclude list of file names or file types when getting list of objects from boto3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58443541/how-to-exclude-list-of-file-names-or-file-types-when-getting-list-of-objects-fro)

Comment: No, that's not what I want. The answer is 3 years old, maybe there is a way to do it now.

Comment: That is what you want and no there is no new way. You need to filter the results yourself, one way or the other. Either get all files and filter afterwards, or get the folders first, filter the folders and then get the files for each valid subfolder.

Comment: do you want to exclude /logs folder ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi yes

Comment: You misunderstand the purpose of the Delimiter parameter.

Comment: Personally, I'd just add an `if` statement in your `for` loop: `if not key.startswith('my_folder/logs/'):` -- that way, it will skip over those keys.

Answer (score 0):

First you should fetch all folders inside `my_folder` using below code

source: airflow s3 hook

```
def list_prefixes(
    bucket_name: Optional[str] = None,
    prefix: Optional[str] = None,
    delimiter: Optional[str] = None,
    page_size: Optional[int] = None,
    max_items: Optional[int] = None,
) -> list:
    """
    Lists prefixes in a bucket under prefix

    :param bucket_name: the name of the bucket
    :param prefix: a key prefix
    :param delimiter: the delimiter marks key hierarchy.
    :param page_size: pagination size
    :param max_items: maximum items to return
    :return: a list of matched prefixes
    :rtype: list
    """
    prefix = prefix or ''
    delimiter = delimiter or ''
    config = {
        'PageSize': page_size,
        'MaxItems': max_items,
    }

    paginator = boto3.client("s3").get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    response = paginator.paginate(
        Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter=delimiter, PaginationConfig=config
    )

    prefixes = []  # type: List[str]
    for page in response:
        if 'CommonPrefixes' in page:
            prefixes.extend(common_prefix['Prefix'] for common_prefix in page['CommonPrefixes'])

    return prefixes
```

After you get list of folders omit the folders you don't want and then fetch the keys inside each folder.